# How to escape dynamic CSS property value

Tags: php, css, redux, escaping

I have the following redux dynamic css included by wp_add_inline_style().

```
// redux dynamic css

global $x_redux_option;
$x_blogpost_overlay_switch = $ x_redux_option [' x_blogpost_overlay_switch];

$x_redux_dynamic_css = '
        .single_post:hover{
          background: ". if ($x_blogpost_overlay_switch == true): echo $x_blogpost_overlay; endif; ." ;
            -webkit-box-shadow: " . if($x_blogpost_overlay_switch == true): ." 0 1px 10px 0 rgba(251,252,252,0.8) " . endif; ." ; 
               -moz-box-shadow: " . if($x_blogpost_overlay_switch == true): . " 0 1px 10px 0 rgba(251,252,252,0.8) " . endif; . " ; 
                    box-shadow: " . if($x_blogpost_overlay_switch == true): . " 0 1px 10px 0 rgba(251,252,252,0.8) " . endif; . " ;
        }
        ';
wp_add_inline_style( 'x-main-style', $x_redux_dynamic_css );
```

Mentor Themeforest Plugin shows the following error:

All dynamic data must be correctly escaped for the context where it is rendered. at file inc/scripts-styles.php, line 213: background: ". if ($x_blogpost_overlay_switch == true): echo $x_blogpost_overlay; endif; ." ;

How can I escape this dynamic  ( $x_blogpost_overlay ) css property value?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this way.

```
global $x_redux_option;
$x_blogpost_overlay_switch = $x_redux_option['x_blogpost_overlay_switch'];

// You must specify this variable as a valid CSS style.
$x_blogpost_overlay = 'white';

$x_redux_dynamic_css = '
        .single_post:hover{
            ';
if ($x_blogpost_overlay_switch == true){
    $x_redux_dynamic_css = $x_redux_dynamic_css . 'background: '. $x_blogpost_overlay . ';' . 
    '-webkit-box-shadow: 0 1px 10px 0 rgba(251,252,252,0.8);
        -moz-box-shadow: 0 1px 10px 0 rgba(251,252,252,0.8); 
             box-shadow: 0 1px 10px 0 rgba(251,252,252,0.8);';
}
$x_redux_dynamic_css .= '}';
wp_add_inline_style( 'x-main-style', $x_redux_dynamic_css );
```

Comment: Thanks much @Miron
Your code works fine. 
But when ($x_blogpost_overlay_switch == true)  there’s a PHP error:
Notice: Undefined variable: x_blogpost_overlay in C:\xampp\htdocs\x\wp-content\themes\x\inc\scripts-styles.php on line 216/////

So now I have used this :

$x_blogpost_overlay = $x_redux_option['x_blogpost_overlay'];

But now the error is:
Notice: Array to string conversion in C:\xampp\htdocs\x\wp-content\themes\x\inc\scripts-styles.php on line 218
I don’t know where the problem is.

Comment: It implies `$x_redux_option['x_blogpost_overlay']` is an array. You must pick one element of the array. Try to use `print_r()` to see which values are in the array and decide which one to pick. For example, `print_r($x_redux_option['x_blogpost_overlay']);`

Comment: I have found this values: Array ( [color] => #666666 [alpha] => 0.25 )  . And now I have used this: $x_redux_dynamic_css = $x_redux_dynamic_css . 'background: '. $x_blogpost_overlay[color] [alpha] . But it's not working. And then I have used this one: $x_redux_dynamic_css = $x_redux_dynamic_css . 'background: '. $x_blogpost_overlay[0] [1]. It's not also working. The PHP error is in the next comment.

Comment: Notice: Use of undefined constant color - assumed 'color' in C:\xampp\htdocs\x\wp-content\themes\x\inc\scripts-styles.php on line 218

Notice: Use of undefined constant alpha - assumed 'alpha' in C:\xampp\htdocs\x\wp-content\themes\x\inc\scripts-styles.php on line 218

Warning: Illegal string offset 'alpha' in C:\xampp\htdocs\x\wp-content\themes\x\inc\scripts-styles.php on line 218

Comment: Look! $x_blogpost_overlay renders color_rgba value from the redux.

Comment: Thank you so much, man :) . I have just noticed that you edited your answer. I have just use your code: $x_blogpost_overlay = 'white';  It's working fine. Look! If I use esc_attr() in my code posted like this : echo esc_attr($x_blogpost_overlay), is it OK? One of the developers in themeforest forum asked me to do so. Is it a proper way, however, Mentor Themeforest doesn't show any error then.

Comment: Then, the `background` property isn't dynamic. You can use `$x_blogpost_overlay = $x_redux_option['x_blogpost_overlay']['color'];`

Comment: Using this $x_blogpost_overlay = 'white'; the background is working dynamically. I have already used the same code for other inline dynamic background css and they are working just awesome :)

Comment: Actually, I have the other query I mentioned in the above comment. If I use  esc_attr($x_blogpost_overlay) in the raw code posted in my post, is it OK? I mean escaping a css property value by esc_attr. However, mentor themeforest plugin doesn't show any error.